# define getter method on object - javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to define *getter* method on object so that when I access a property  , getter method fires

```
object.someProperty // this fires object.get(name) where name is someProperty
```

---

this is an example illustrate my thought

**file : data.js**

```
import setting from 'setting';

const data = {
    a : {
        foo : 1 ,
        bar : 2
    } ,
    b : {
        foo : 3 ,
        bar : 4
    }
}

//DEFINE GETTER
//something like this
data.DEFINE_GETTER(function(property)
{
    if(setting.type === 'a')
        return data['a'][property];
    else
        return data['b'][property];
})

export default data;
```

**file : test.js**

```
import data from 'data';
import setting from 'setting';

setting.type = 'a';
console.log(data.foo)   //should be 1
console.log(data.bar)   //should be 2

setting.type = 'b';
console.log(data.foo)   //should be 3
console.log(data.bar)   //should be 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at [**Proxies**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).

```js
const data = {
    a : {
        foo : 1 ,
        bar : 2
    } ,
    b : {
        foo : 3 ,
        bar : 4
    }
}

const setting = {
  type: 'a'
};

const products = new Proxy({
     data: data
   },
   {
     get: function(obj, prop) {
       return obj.data[setting.type][prop];
     },
     set: function(obj, prop, value) {
       obj.data[setting.type][prop] = value;
     } 
   });

console.log('Before type change');
console.log(products.foo);

setting.type = 'b';

console.log('After type change');
console.log(products.foo);

products.foo = 4;

console.log('After value change');
console.log(products.foo);

setting.type = 'a';

console.log('After type change');
console.log(products.foo);
```

Comment: the problem data object have a lot of properties , what i'm looking for is method fires with `property` parameter

Answer (score 1):

You can define a `getter`

```
Object.defineProperty(data, 'foo', {
  get: function() { return this[setting.type].foo }
});
Object.defineProperty(data, 'bar', {
  get: function() { return this[setting.type].bar }
});
```

**Edit**

You can refactor the `defineProperty` to a method that iterate all the different keys in the `data`

```
function defineDataProp( obj, setting )
{
  Object.keys(Object.values( obj )[0]).forEach( function(key){
      Object.defineProperty(obj, key, {
         get: function() { return this[setting.type][ key ] }
      });
  })
}
```

**Demo**

```js
const data = {
    a : { foo : 1 , bar : 2 } ,
    b : { foo : 3 , bar : 4 }
};

var setting = { "type" : "a" };
defineDataProp( data, setting );

setting.type = 'a';
console.log(data.foo,data.bar)   

setting.type = 'b';
console.log(data.foo,data.bar)

function defineDataProp( obj, setting )
{
  Object.keys(Object.values( obj )[0]).forEach( function(key){
      Object.defineProperty(obj, key, {
         get: function() { return this[setting.type][ key ] }
      });
  })
}
```

Comment: the problem data object have a lot of properties , what i'm looking for is method fires with `property` parameter

Comment: You can refactor the code which takes property parameter instead of `foo` or `bar` specically and define their getters. Let me know if you need help with that.

Answer (score 1):

Use proxy handler

```
let handler = {
    get(target, propKey, receiver) {
        console.log('get ' + propKey);
        if(setting.type === 'a')
        return data['a'][propKey];
    else
        return data['b'][propKey];
    }
};
let proxyData = new Proxy(data, handler);
// now you can call
proxyData.foo
proxyData.bar
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a plunker that may help https://plnkr.co/edit/eRsgBXQackUgZkg84lZj?p=info

> First of all if you want to access any property from an object that
>   must be in that object.

So, data.foo will be usable only when you create an object/function of foo inside data.

> Now we need a dynamic pointing object that point to
>   Data.Child.Childobjects

So, I created a function AddProperty just pass the name of ParentObject and childchildobject. Write your logic inside it.

```
var setting = {type : null};
var data = {
    a : {
        foo : 1 ,
        bar : 2
    } ,
    b : {
        foo : 3 ,
        bar : 4
    }
}
function AddProperty(baseObject = null, ChildChildProperty = null)
 {
   if(baseObject != null && ChildChildProperty != null)
   {
     Object.defineProperty(baseObject, ChildChildProperty, {
    get: function() {
        if(setting.type === 'a')
        return data['a'][ChildChildProperty];
    else
        return data['b'][ChildChildProperty];
    },
    set: function(name) {
       if(setting.type === 'a')
        data['a'][ChildChildProperty] = name;
    else
        data['b'][ChildChildProperty] = name;
    }
});
   }
 }

AddProperty(data,'foo');
AddProperty(data,'bar');

setting.type = 'a';
console.log(data.foo)   //should be 1
console.log(data.bar)   //should be 2

setting.type = 'b';
console.log(data.foo)   //should be 3
console.log(data.bar)   //should be 4
```